# How to write java code for file transfer to IBM MQ preserving the file name

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to write a script in java to automatically do the file transfer to IBM MQ. Note, that even if I get the message on the other end, I still want that message to preserve the original file name.

Basically, I want the equivalent of this command prompt in java:

```sh
-bash-4.1$ /opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/bin/java -jar imqsput.jar --channel=REMOTE.ADMIN.... --host=.... --input=test/20190918_153009858_Test.txt --manager=... --port=1414 --queue=... &>> testoutput1.out
```

The file name must be preserved in this case as it is read by the app from the message later.

So far I've got something standard like this:

```java
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;

import com.ibm.jms.*;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;

MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
factory.setHostName("tcp://.......");
factory.setPort(1414);
factory.setQueueManager(".......");
factory.setChannel("REMOTE.ADMIN........");

Connection connection = factory.createConnection("......", "........");

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

String content=vars.get("processedTestData");

MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///.......");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

Message message = session.createTextMessage(content);

producer.send(message);
connection.close();
```

But instead of String content I want to send a file in the same way as the imqsput does. Any way of doing it in java?

Description for the imqsput:

```
IMQsPUT allows loading files into IBM message queues.
 -c,--channel <CHANNEL>                 The channel used to access the
                                        queue. Alternatively can be
                                        replaced by specifying a client
                                        definition.
    --ccsid <CCSID>                     The target encoding/charset/ccsid
                                        to be used for messages being
                                        written to the queue. The default
                                        is '1208'.
                                        The following CCSIDs can be used:
                                        http://www-01.ibm.com/software/glo
                                        balization/ccsid/ccsid_registered.
                                        html
    --charset <CHARSET>                 The charset to be used for reading
                                        input files. The default is
                                        'UTF-8'. The following values are
                                        valid: 'US-ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1',
                                        'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-16LE',
                                        'UTF-16'.
    --cipher-suite <SUITE>              The cipher suite for the secure
                                        connections.
 -d,--definition <URL>                  URL to the client channel
                                        definition (CCDT). Must include
                                        the protocol like file:///. If
                                        this is not set, then the host,
                                        post and channel parameters must
                                        be set.
 -h,--host <HOST>                       The hostname/IP address of the
                                        machine hosting the queues.
 -i,--input <FILE1/PATH1,FILE2/PATH2>   A comma separated list of files
                                        and directories which should be
                                        loaded onto the queue.
    --keystore-file <FILE>              Sets the keystore, used for secure
                                        connections.Establishes a secure
                                        connection to the queue.
    --keystore-password <PASSWORD>      Optional password for the keystore
                                        to be used with the
                                        --keystore-file option.
 -m,--manager <MANAGER>                 The name of the queue manager.
                                        Alternatively can be replaced by
                                        specifying a client definition.
 -p,--port <PORT>                       The port used to access the queue
                                        manager. If not set 1414 is used.
                                        Alternatively can be replaced by
                                        specifying a client definition.
 -q,--queue <QUEUE>                     The name of the Queue.
 -r,--remove-original                   Deletes the original input file
                                        when it was successfully written
                                        to the queue.
 -R,--rename-failed <EXTENSION>         When set, files which failed to
                                        transmit will be renamed by
                                        appending the given extension to
                                        the filename. Files which already
                                        have this extension will not be
                                        processed again (only relevant
                                        when transmitting a folder).
    --ssl-debug                         If this is enabled, then a SSL
                                        trace will be generated.
    --truststore-file <FILE>            Sets the truststore, used for
                                        secure connections.
    --truststore-password <PASSWORD>    Optional password for the
                                        truststore to be used with the
                                        --truststore-file option
 -u,--unique-message-id                 When set, the message ID is set to
                                        a randomly generated String,
                                        otherwhise, the filename is used.
```

[Class diagram for imqsput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqY0V.png)

Comment: What is `imqsput.jar`, where did you obtain this?   If it works why are you rewritingit?

Comment: I need to check more with the devs, it might be modified version of this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030210_.htm

But the reason, I don't want to use it because I want the auto-framework to do it for me. And running script from the code feels not a right thing to do. I would rather have "proper" coded solution to this. Also, that using that jar actually makes the overall thing look and feel ugly as you have to connect to the second machine, copy files and then run the imqsput...

Comment: But you are right, I will check the contents and see if it actually works for me

Comment: @DOgl You referred to a C++ program in the IBM documentation, but your software is a Java program `imqsput.jar`. Can you explain how the app reads the message from the queue? You could put the file name as a message property, e.g. `message.setStringProperty("FILE_NAME", "test/20190918_153009858_Test.txt");`.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel.  There is a free open source Java project that can send & receive files via IBM MQ called: Universal File Mover.  You can find it here: https://capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html

Comment: @Daniel Hi Daniel, added the description on imqsput. It feels that it is either an earlier utility from IBM, which is no longer available or bespoke compilation of something similar to amqsput or a combination of 2. The reason I am using it is because it was tool of choice in the environment I am working on. Which has strict limitations on the amount of things you can bring in.

Comment: @Roger, well, I don't need to just move the file, I need a java code to do that, not an application. Because it is part of the framework I am building - moving the file is essential, but just part of it. And I would prefer that solution not to call 3rd Party apps if possible (certainly not ones driven by GUI)

Comment: @DanielSteinmann also, I have added the class diagram (part of it) for the imqsput.jar.

Comment: DOgl, I guess you didn't read much on the link Roger sent.  The GUI is just a add on "monitor" the actual file mover is all config file based.  It is licensed under  Apache License 2, it is Java based, use IBM MQ to move the files, and the source code download is available, so you could integrate it into your framework however you wanted, or at the very least see how it handles sending and receiving files.

Comment: @JoshMc I have downloaded the Unix version, which I then unzipped and looked at. It has some jars in it. I couldn't find the docs though on how the code works apart from the Roger's blog, which I still need to study as it is quite a bit of info.

Comment: I see it has `Universal File Mover Status Monitor source code.` thought you would want the source?  The is also `Universal File Mover Installation and Operation Manual` under Manuals link.

Comment: @DOgl the manuals are located here: https://capitalware.com/ufm_manuals.html  The source code is on the UFM Downloads page called "Universal File Mover source code".  Yes, the UFM Status Monitor is a GUI program but it is optional.  UFM itself is not a GUI program.

Comment: DOgl, if I understand correctly, you want to send a file as a message to queue or the other way round may be. So have you tried using MQ's managed file transfer bundled with IBM MQ? Its commonly known as IBM MQ MFT. This will have solution to your scenario.